# Saving data in database for Monopoly game

Tags: database, database-design

Let's say I have an app (a Monopoly game) with many users, where each user has a balance, and they make transactions between them.

I have a table with all the users (userID, name, email) and a table with all the transactions and the users who made them (user1, user 2, amount).

Now if I need to present a balance for each user, would it be better to keep the balance for each user in the users table and update it every time a transaction is made, or should I calculate it from the transactions table every time I wont to present it? Assume this game will have a lot of traffic, so what is a more reasonable approach for 10,000+ users and about 120,000+ transactions per week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a new column balance in the user table is a redundancy beacause the value could be calculated with a query on the transactions table.

However one of the DB design process is the estimation of how many read and writes could happen on a particular table. If this estimation is high it's logic and permitted to simplify the result of some read or write and have a redundancy on the DB to afford the many reads requested by the web pages and display values with less processing time.

In your case the balance column update could be done with a trigger on the transactions table that calculate the balance for the two users involed.